# slideUp/slideDown using Pure CSS

Tags: css, html

I am using the following code to display menu and display submenu when hovered on the menus. I want to add some animation for the submenu when it is displayed like what slideUp and slideDown in jQuery. But I want to use pure CSS for this. What alterations should I make in the code do achieve it?

```
<div id="main_nav">
    <ul>
        <li >
            <a href="#" >Item 0</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Item 1
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 1 0</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1 2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Item 1 2 0</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Item 3</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item 3 0</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>




#main_nav ul,#main_nav ul ul{
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
#main_nav ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    background-color:#1b1b1b;
    padding:0 10px 10px;
}
#main_nav ul li:hover>*{
    display:block;
}
#main_nav ul li{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0;
    float:left;
}
#main_nav ul li:hover{
    z-index:1;

}
#main_nav ul ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}
#main_nav ul{
    font-size:0;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
}
* html #main_nav ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
}
#main_nav ul>li{
    margin:0;
}
#main_nav ul a{
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
#main_nav ul ul li{
    float:none;
    margin:10px 0 0;
}
#main_nav ul ul a{
    text-align:left;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#1b1b1b;
    font-size: 12px ;
    color:#FFF;
}
#main_nav ul li:hover>a{
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#2b97dd;
    opacity:90%;
}
#main_nav ul ul li:hover>a{
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    opacity:90%;

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Midhun28/ZstjT/

Comment: A Pure CSS way would be to use CSS transitions.

Comment: Can you give an example??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8252c/

Comment: Without setting fixed height to dropdown you cant do it. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/ZstjT/9/

Comment: @VikasGhodke you don't need fixed heights http://jsfiddle.net/ZstjT/10/

Comment: You kind of do. Animating some arbitrary max-height value doesn't produce consistent animations across all sub-menus, unless they are all even

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to fake it in plain CSS is by animating the `top` property:

```
li{
  z-index: 10;   /* <- must appear above the animation */
}

ul ul{
  visibility: hidden;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: -5; 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.4s, opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;         
}

li:hover > ul{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;    
  top: 58px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

And hide the `overflow` on the menu container, or put some element with higher `z-index` above the menu and fill it with color.

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/mmnUT/) I've clean-up up some of your CSS, much of it was not needed

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to see what was the jQuery SlideUp doing in attribute style, so I tried to take a screenshot (easier to see than looking at the code :P)

Here it is :)
[image: Console view of element style attributes changing]

So, it's possible to replicate this animation with CSS3.
Just animate the margin, padding and height  and you will be able to get the same effect as jQuery.